# People Picker Events

Tags: 2007, people-picker

Does anyone know if:

1. there is an event that fires when the name in a people picker field changes?
2. there is an event that fires when the Browse (Address Book) dialog closes?

I'm using MOSS 2007 and enhancing things on the client using JavaScript and jQuery, etc. and need to know when the name in a (non multi-select) people picker field changes. I'm hoping there is an event that fires either when the name changes or else when when the Browse (Address Book) dialog closes (in the case where the user chooses to use the Address Book). My hope is that there is an event that fires (under one of the circumstances I've mentioned) so I can use jQuery to bind it to a handler and code what I need to do inside that handler.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a global function that gets invoked named "EntityEditorCallback". If you want to have your own code run after that function is complete, you can override the function so that your own events get run after it. Note this function runs after the people picker has resolved value of the field to an actual sharepoint user.

See this stack overflow post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328016/i-need-jquery-to-fire-when-people-picker-returns-the-value-to-the-main-form-from

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right for at least first point.
1) When the name in a people picker field changes 'onChange' event (javascript) of the containing DIV gets fired. It calls 'updateControlValue('Picker')' method from init.js.